# How to change the node version by mupx and how to check the installed node my mupx on aws ec2 by ssh

Tags: node.js, meteor, deployment, amazon-ec2, meteor-up

I am getting error while deploying the meteor 1.3 and meteor 1.4 project to aws ubuntu ec2.

the error complains about the npm version , saying that the npm version should atleast be 2 and it cannot read /bundle/package.json

In the mup.json file i changed the node version to 6.7.0 and others so that i get the npm which is greater or equal to version 2. After changing i again ran mupx setup, mupx deploy but again the same error, and in logs i could see that the node and npm version are not changed

```
-----------------------------------STDERR----------------------------    
npm@2, which has some small
npm WARN deprecated backwards-incompatible changes made to npm run-script and
npm WARN deprecated semver behavior.
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: /bundle/bundle/programs/server/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file.     JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-98-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i"
npm ERR! cwd /bundle/bundle/programs/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.43
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.29
npm ERR! file /bundle/bundle/programs/server/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

=> Redeploying previous version of the app

-----------------------------------STDOUT-----------------------------------

To see more logs type 'mup logs --tail=50'

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So i thought of manually logging to the aws instance and change the node version over there.

when i logged, firstly when i ran some commands like meteor, node i could see that commands are not found and when i had ran mupx setup it had successfully set up the system.

So next i installed node and npm to the latest version and i came back to my meteor project.
I changed the mup.json file by commenting on setupNode,because i already have node to my latest version on my aws ec2 ubuntu.

I ran mupx setup, mupx deploy but again the same error.

So the question is how do i actually change my node version for the meteor project and how does mup setup up the environment on the ec2 instance and where on it, as when i logged in i could not see any commad being accepted, So how does the meteor pick up the installed dependencies and from where.

Comment: Have you upgraded mup to the latest version?

Comment: yes I have updated

Comment: any solution to this?